# How to make a jquery plugin work on user defined elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm making a basic jQuery plugin with which the user can change Bg-color, font-color etc.

I want the user of the plugin to be able to define the elements on which these changes become active.

I know I have to use 'this' but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code for the plugin

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){
//Define your own variables first

var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
var p = $('p');

//Define the default settings here
var settings = {
    textColor: 'red'
};


//Write your methods here
var methods = {
    //Call this method to initialize the plugin
    init: function(){
        console.log("Initialize the plugin");
        $('input').on('change', methods.changeColor);
        $('select').on('change', methods.changeFont);
        $('.slider').on('change', methods.changeWidth);
    },

    changeColor: function(){
        console.log("This will change the background and/or font color");

        var userBackgroundColor = $("#userBackgroundColor").val();
        var userTextColor = $("#userTextColor").val().toLocaleLowerCase();

        wrapper.css({
            backgroundColor: userBackgroundColor,
            color: userTextColor
        });
    },

    changeFont: function(){
        console.log("This will change the font");

        var userFontSize = $("option:selected").val();

        console.log(userFontSize);

        p.css({
            fontSize: userFontSize + 'em'
        })
    },

    changeWidth: function(){
        var p = $('p');
        var userWidth = $(".slider").val();

        var widthFontChange = userWidth / 20;

        if (widthFontChange == 1) {
            p.css({
                width: userWidth + '%',
                fontSize: widthFontChange + 'em'
            });
        }


        else {
            widthFontChange = userWidth / 2;
            p.css({
                width: userWidth + '%',
                fontSize: widthFontChange + 'px'
            })
        }
    }

};



//Actual plugin call
$.fn.pluginName = function(options){
    //If the user overrides defaults by setting his own options
    if(options){
        settings = $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    //Put any eventHandlers here, like this:
    this.on('change', methods.changeColor);
    this.on('change', methods.changeFont);
    this.on('change', methods.changeWidth);

    //Init the plugin with the $selector
    methods.init(this);

    //Return this for jQuery chaining
    return this;
};
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

And this is the file in which the user wil be able to define the object on which the plugin has to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').pluginName();
});
```

My question is, how to I make this work the way I want it to?

Comment: I need something practical to show a working example. Can you give an example of how you would want to use this plugin? Start with this basic JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CgGjq/ and fill in some HTML content and some examples of operations you want it to perform.

Comment: Did that. So what I want to do is this. When you slide the slider, the p text changes size. But I want to give the plugin user the opportunity to change this to, for example, the h1.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Never used JSFiddle before ;) This is the new link. I hope. http://jsfiddle.net/CgGjq/2/

Comment: I put a simple answer below, but your current plugin is not usable across multiple elements. There is too much hard-wired to global selectors (like `.wrapper` and paragraphs `p`). These also need to become properties of the plugin (put them in the options).

Comment: Oh oké, I get it. Thanks for your help! I now know what the problem is.

Comment: The whole plugin needs to be an object, rather than just static methods. You can then store `$element` and `options` as properties of `this` and provider selectors for the target elements too. With the current style of code you can only have one of these on a page.

Comment: As all full-blown JQuery plugins have the same basic behaviour, I created a helper that does all the wrapping, creating and calling etc for multiple jQuery elements. Unfortunately it is written in TypeScript so the js version is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to provide settings to choose the various components to listen for changes. If so...

Pass the jQuery `this` and the `options` to your `init` method, so it has everything it needs to hook up events to specific child elements.

I switched to using the delegated version of `on` as it will survive dynamic changes.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CgGjq/6/

The key part is

```
init: function ($element, options) {
            console.log("Initialize the plugin");
            $element.on('change', options.input || 'input', methods.changeColor);
            $element.on('change', options.select || 'select', methods.changeFont);
            $element.on('change', options.slider || '.slider', methods.changeWidth);
        },
```

Which uses properties in the options to override the selectors (or default to your plugin defaults settings if not supplied).

You can then use it with options like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').pluginName({
        select: '#userFontSize', // Override the selectors etc
        slider: "#userWidth.slider"
    });
});
```

Comment: Well what I actually meant to do was change the elements on which the changes become active. For example, the slider will work on the h1 if the users says so, instead of the p it works on now. Thanks for this though, code is much better like this.